# Is my Google maps API key publicly exposed when I set a restriction as localhost

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-3

To use Google maps Javascript API in my Angular app, I add the script tag in my index.html file like the docs say;

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKeyHere&libraries=places&callback=initPlaces" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now from the picture below you can see that I've created website restrictions and added my sites urls running in the Azure cloud. But I need to run this locally (https://localhost:4200) as well for development.

**QUESTION** - If I add localhost:4200 as one of the restrictions, like shown below, does this give public access to anyone who wants to use my key on their machine? If so, how do I prevent this as the key is hard coded in the script tag preventing me from using different keys? Or is there a way to reload the key dynamically if I'm locally developing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how Google protect your API key based on the websites?

It's not magic, it's encrypted, it's not encoded, it's simply HTTP request. so How? It's simply the HOST header that is checked, no more.

So, anyone that have a localhost host can reuse your key. And, as you felt, anyone on their dev machine!

---

To fix that, I simply recommend to have 2 keys! One publicly released and you autorise only "mysite" DNS on it.

A second one, that you never share and that you restrict with localhost.

Like that, you separate the public and the private exposure.

Comment: Hi Guillaume. The problem with using 2 different keys for me is the script tag, as seen above. It needs a hard coded key value. So if I have two keys and develop locally then build and push to an Azure server I have to manually change the key in the script tag each time. I'm looking for a way to prevent having to do this.

Comment: Use CI/CD when you deploy. And automate the key override when you build the cloud application. It's done for that! Do nothing manually!

Comment: Hi Guillaume, what's CI/CD?

Comment: Continuous Integration/ Continuous Deployment (or Delivery). Do you use Azure Devops?

Comment: I use Azure, but not DevOps. I assume that's a service in Azure? Will this help me build and push my website to my dev and prod servers using the correct DB's and other build parameters?

Comment: Yes, it automate the deployment processes.

Comment: Hi Guillaume. I know I can go to Microsoft to see docs, but I was wondering if you used any tutorials to learn DevOps? Maybe a document or tutorial that provides examples and pictures/videos. Microsoft docs are pretty dry and verbose and sometimes boring to read.

Comment: DevOps is a wide topic. CI/CD is a tool to achieve DevOps. The most important is to understand the concept: When your code change an automatic process take it, test it, package it and deploy it. It's more or less bash script that run commands, change files, move directories and that's all. In fact all the things that you do manually, you put them in a script and you let the CI/CD tool doing all the commands for you!!

Comment: Hi Guillaume. Do you know any sites or documentation that would help me in setting up the correct environment for CI/CD? Ex. the proper way to set up my dev server, production server, dev and prod database and anything else that would be needed before I go live.